# On a schoolchild puzzle of V.I. Arnold (re: toric varieties)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

When reading [the interview with Vladimir Arnold](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/%7Elekheng/interviews/VladimirArnold.pdf) in the April 1997 edition of the Notices, I came across the following anecdote.

> Many Russian families have the
> tradition of giving hundreds of such
> problems to their children, and mine
> was no exception. The first real
> mathematical experience I had was when
> our schoolteacher I. V. Morozkin gave
> us the following problem: Two old
> women started at sunrise and each
> walked at a constant velocity. One
> went from A to B and the other from B
> to A. They met at noon and, continuing
> with no stop, arrived respectively at
> B at 4 p.m. and at A at 9 p.m. At what
> time was the sunrise on this day?
>
> I spent a whole day thinking on this
> oldie, and the solution (based on what
> is now called scaling arguments,
> dimensional analysis, or toric variety
> theory, depending on your taste) came
> as a revelation.

I found the solution in a rather straightfoward fashion, but I was curious as to the parenthetic remark. So, can anybody tell me (as a total outsider to algebraic geometry), what does this problem have to do with toric varieties?

Comment: While we are at it, what do toric varieties have to do with dimensional analysis?

Comment: Units can be seen as monomials... 

Comment: Dimensional analysis is abstractly the study of the action of (K*)^n on K[x_1, ... x_n].  One should think of each of the x_i as having different units and (K*)^n as describing what happens to quantities (homogeneous elements) as we change units.  And I am told that actions of tori have something to do with toric varieties.

Comment: It seems to me that this problem has nothing whatsoever to do with "scaling arguments, dimensional analysis, or toric variety theory".
On the other hand the underlying proportion
x:y=y:z
is the equation of my favorite toric singularity.
PS I am now sorely tempted to ask this question to my daughter this evening :-).

Comment: If you scale the velocities of both women and the distance between A and B all by the same amount, of course you get the same answer. That makes it possible to arrange any value you like for one velocity, or for the distance from A to B. 

Comment: Regarding dimensional analysis and toric varieties, this paper gives an exposition http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6659

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem cannot be solved because the sun rises at different times at A and B in general
(say A = Vladivostok and B = Moscow).  All what can be said is that (12-tA)(12-tB) = 4x9 = 36.
If by chance the sun rise times are identical then tA = tB = 6.
This is obtained by using the similitude of triangles in the space-time diagram.

Comment: An old woman walking from Vladivostok to Moscow in one day is certainly in very good shape.