# How do we give mathematical meaning to 'physical dimensions'?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

In so-called 'natural unit', it is said that physical quantities are measured in the dimension of 'mass'. For example, $\text{[length]=[mass]}^{-1}$ and so on.

In quantum field theory, the dimension of coupling constant is very important because it determines renormalizability of the theory.

However, I do not see what exactly the mathematical meaning of 'physical dimension' is. For example, suppose we have self-interaction terms $g_1\cdot \phi\partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi$ and $g_2 \cdot \phi^4$,  where $\phi$ is a real scalar field, $g_i$ are coupling constants and we assume $4$ dimensional spacetime.

Then, it is stated in standard physics books that the scalar field is of mass dimension $1$ and so $g_1$ must be of mass dimension $-1$ and $g_2$ is dimensionless. But, these numbers do not seem to play any 'mathematical' role.

To clarify my questions,

1. What forbids me from proclaiming that $\phi$ is dimensionless instead of mass dimension $1$?
2. What is the exact difference between a dimensionless coupling constant and a coupling constant of mass dimension $-1$?

These issues seem very fundamental but always confuse me. Could anyone please provide a precise answer?

Comment: The term is "[dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis)". Wikipedia has a section on mathematical formulation. Your specific questions might fit better on [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) but I am not qualified enough to say for sure.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, a quantity with a non-trivial physical dimension is [acted non-trivially on by the multiplicative group of positive real numbers](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/), which implicitly corresponds to rescaling a particular unit. This may or may not help your intuition on this point.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52585/

Comment: if you are even interested in some applications you can check Barenblatt's book "scaling, self similraity and intermediate asymptotics"and Goldenfeld's book on phase transitions and renormalization group

Comment: You ask whether you have some choice in defining what has what units. In general you do, although consistency will generally require that if you change the definition of one quantity's units, you make changes to the units of other quantities as well. A paper that gets into this is Dicke, “Mach’s principle and invariance under transformation of units,” Phys Rev 125 (1962) 2163. For example, there are various inconsistent conventions as to what units the metric should have in general relativity. I have a treatment of this topic in sec. 5.11 of my GR book: 
http://www.lightandmatter.com/genrel/

Comment: Sorry if this has been posted already, Terence Tao wrote about dimensional analysis 
https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/
A few interesting takeaways, e.g. the discussion on the AM-GM inequalities and mixing of dimensions

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Mathematically, the concept of a physical dimension is expressed using one-dimensional vector spaces and their tensor products.

For example, consider mass.
You can add masses together and you know how to multiply a mass by a real number.
Thus, masses should form a one-dimensional real vector space $M$.

The same reasoning applies to other physical quantities, like length, time, temperature, etc.
Denote the corresponding one-dimensional vector spaces by $L$, $T$, etc.

When you multiply (say) some mass $m∈M$ and some length $l∈L$,
the result is $m⊗l∈M⊗L$.
Here $M⊗L$ is another one-dimensional real vector space,
which is capable of “storing” physical quantities of dimension mass times length.

Multiplicative inverses live in the dual space:
if $m∈M$, then $m^{-1}∈M^*$, where $\def\Hom{\mathop{\rm Hom}} \def\R{{\bf R}} M^*=\Hom(M,\R)$.
The element $m^{-1}$ is defined as the unique element in $M^*$
such that $m^{-1}(m)=1$, where $-(-)$ denotes the evaluation
of a linear functional on $M$ on an element of $M$.
Observe that $m ⊗ m^{-1} ∈ M⊗M^* ≅ \R$, where the latter canonical isomorphism
sends $(f,m)$ to $f(m)$, so $m^{-1}$ is indeed the inverse of $m$.

Next, you can also define powers of physical quantities,
i.e., $m^t$, where $m∈M$ is a mass and $t∈\R$ is a real number.
This is done using the notion of a *density* from differential geometry.
(The case $\def\C{{\bf C}} t\in\C$ works similarly, but with
complex one-dimensional vector spaces.)
In order to do this, we must make $M$ into an *oriented* vector space.
For a one-dimensional vector space, this simply means that
we declare one out of the two half-rays in $M∖\{0\}$ to be positive,
and denote it by $M_{>0}$.
This makes perfect sense for physical quantities like mass, length, temperature.

Once you have an orientation on $M$,
you can define $\def\Dens{\mathop{\rm Dens}} \Dens_d(M)$
for $d∈\R$ as the one-dimensional (oriented) real vector space
whose elements are equivalence classes of pairs $(a,m)$,
where $a∈\R$, $m∈M_{>0}$.
The equivalence relation is defined as follows:
$(a,b⋅m)∼(a b^d,m)$ for any $b∈\R_{>0}$.
The vector space operations are defined as follows:
$0=(0,m)$ for some $m∈M_{>0}$,
$-(a,m)=(-a,m)$,
$(a,m)+(a',m)=(a+a',m)$,
and $s(a,m)=(sa,m)$.
It suffices to add pairs with the same
second component $m$ because the equivalence relation allows you to change the second component arbitrarily.

Once we have defined $\Dens_d(M)$, given $m∈M_{>0}$ and $d∈\R$,
we define $m^d∈\Dens_d(M)$ as the equivalence class of the pair $(1,m)$.
It is easy to verify that all the usual laws of arithmetic,
like $m^d m^e = m^{d+e}$, $m^d n^d = (mn)^d$, etc.,
are satisfied, provided that multiplication and reciprocals are interpreted as explained above.

Using the power operation operations we just defined,
we can now see that the equivalence class of $(a,m)$
is equal to $a⋅m^d$, where $m∈M_{>0}$, $m^d∈\Dens_d(M)_{>0}$,
and $a⋅m^d∈\Dens_d(M)$.
This makes the meaning of the equivalence relation clear.

In particular, for $d=-1$ we have a canonical isomorphism $\Dens_{-1}(M)→M^*$
that sends the equivalence class of $(1,m)$ to the element $m^{-1}∈M^*$ defined above,
so the two notions of a reciprocal element coincide.

If you are dealing with temperature without knowing about the absolute zero,
it can be modeled as a one-dimensional real *affine* space.
That is, you can make sense of a linear combination
$$a_1 t_1 + a_2 t_2 + a_3 t_3$$
of temperatures $t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3$
as long as $a_1+a_2+a_3=1$,
and you don't need to know about the absolute zero to do this.
The calculus of physical quantities can be extended
to one-dimensional real affine spaces without much difficulty.

None of the above constructions make any noncanonical choices of
physical units (such as a unit of mass, for example).
Of course, if you do fix such a unit $μ∈M_{>0}$, you can construct
an isomorphism $\R→\Dens_d(M)$ that sends $a∈\R$ to $aμ^d$,
and the above calculus (including the power operations)
is identified with the usual operations on real numbers.

In general relativity, we no longer have a single one-dimensional
vector space for length.
Instead, we have the *tangent bundle*,
whose elements model (infinitesimal) displacements.
Thus, physical quantities no longer live in a fixed one-dimensional
vector space, but rather are sections of a one-dimensional
vector bundle constructed from the tangent bundle.
For example, the volume is an element of the total space
of the line bundle of 1-densities $\Dens_1(T M)$,
and the length is now given by the line-bundle of $λ$-densities $\Dens_λ(T M)$, where $λ=1/\dim M$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the answer I have sought.

Comment: Very interesting! But how well defined is the multiplication of a Kelvin temperature by a scalar, say 2?

Comment: @Wolfgang: If you are talking about kelvins as a unit of measurement for temperature, this means you know about the absolute zero and temperature is an element of a real vector space.  In this case, multiplication by 2 is well-defined, corresponding, in physical terms, to doubling the average kinetic energy of particles in the system.  For scales without absolute zero, multiplication by 2 is not defined, only affine combinations are defined, since temperatures in this case form a one-dimensional real affine space.

Comment: Can you expand on the GR case? Having a fixed metric in our spacetime, how would we go about defining a global notion of length, for example? I'd also love to hear if this can be used to compare measurements in different inertial frames in SR.

Comment: @user347489: The metric $g$ is a bilinear form on the tangent bundle that takes values in $L⊗L$, i.e., has physical dimension length squared.  If we have a curve $γ$, we can make sense of $g(γ'(t),γ'(t))^{1/2}∈L$, as described in the answer.  This yields a function valued in $L$, which we can integrate over the domain of $γ$.  The result is an element of $L$, which is the length of $γ$.

Comment: Did you come up with this on your own? I have never seen this written down anywhere.

Comment: @DeaneYang: Did you mean to say degrees Celsius?  Degrees Kelvin can certainly be rescaled in a meaningful way (in fact, formulas like kT/2 in physics do exactly this).

Comment: @DimitriPavlov, you're right. There is absolute zero and units of temperature can be rescaled relative to that.

Comment: @DeaneYang: Densities can be found in some textbooks; nLab some some references (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/density), although I am not sure if these were the sources I used when I learned this concept.  Specializing to the case of base manifolds that are points is a straightforward step from there.

Comment: I clearly remember accepting this answer yesterday...but it seems that an error occurred. Now I have just accepted this answer.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov, I was referring specifically to your first sentence. It is actually relevant to much more than physical quantities, but anything that can be measured by a single number and where subtraction of two measurements is meaningful. Some measurements are affine so you cannot do tensor products, but when the measurement is a relative one, then you can use duals and tensor products. It's a completely rigorous framework for dimensional analysis. It's useful in many contexts. In analysis, the relevant word is "scaling".

Comment: @DeaneYang: I have not seen it presented in this specific form in the literature, definitely not with densities.  I was thinking about densities at some point, wondering how to define the line of densities for a single vector space, as opposed to just a bundle (where you can simply take powers of transition functions).  Once I figured this out, it became clear that for one-dimensional spaces this gives a coordinate-free way to take powers of their elements, such as physical quantities.

Comment: @DeaneYang: There is a notion of a tensor product for affine spaces, and it is defined in the obvious way (using representing objects for biaffine maps).  That's what I meant when I said that the theory can also be extended to one-dimensional affine real spaces, although I have not seen it in the literature.

Comment: Does the need for non-integer dimensional powers ever arise in physics? Why can’t one ‘survive’ on tensor products and dual spaces alone?

Comment: @user3840170, fractional powers do appear. The square root of time in the heat equation, for example.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov, is there an example of where the tensor product of affine spaces arises naturally or could potentially be useful? I’d never seen them before but the idea sounds intriguing.

Comment: @user3840170 There are absolutely fractional powers of quantities and units in physics! In addition to Deane Yang example above, in noise analysis one frequently refers to and plots the square root of the spectral density function of a random process, whose units are $\mathrm{V}/\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}$, $\mathrm{A}/\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}$ etc.

Comment: @DeaneYang: I can certainly think of examples where an affine quantity (like temperature without absolute zero) is multiplied or divided by a vector quantity (like length), which needs the tensor product of an affine space and a vector space.  I am not sure about two affine quantities.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov, sorry about hassling you about this, but could you give a specific example? I don't doubt there is one, but I'm unable, with my limited knowledge and perspective, to find one. There is a decent chance that if you provide one, then I'll say "but of course. That's obvious!"

Comment: @DeaneYang: This is a rather stupid example, but the enthalpy change of a reaction in a calorimeter is given by the formula $C T_2 - C T_1$, where $C$ is the heat capacity (measured in units of energy times inverse temperature), and $T_1$ and $T_2$ are temperatures, which can be elements of the affine line of temperatures (without absolute zero).  Now $C T_1$ and $C T_2$ are elements in the tensor product of the affine line of temperatures and the real one-dimensional vector space of heat capacities.

Comment: @DeaneYang: Another natural example is given by the concept of potential energy in physics, which is naturally axiomatized as a real affine line, since defining the state with potential energy 0 is often a matter of arbitrary choice.  In physics, there are many formulas where the potential energy is multiplied or divided by another quantity, and these formulas can be interpreted as giving elements in tensor products of an affine line and a 1-dimensional real vector space.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov, thanks for the examples. Although I see your point, I'm not entirely convinced. But, as you say, in both it is the change that matters and that the affine quantities themselves. So the first one I would write as $C(T_2-T_1)$ and the second is $F(D_2-D_1)$. The point in both is that the choice of $0$ is arbitrary, so the affine quantity is not physically meaningful. It is needed only when you make measurements, but even then, you don't even have to allow $0$ as a valid measurement. I view the affine quantity as analogous to a choice of gauge in more sophisticated theories.

Comment: @DeaneYang: Your argument is conceptually similar to saying that we don't need one-dimensional real vector spaces, since what matters ultimately is the _ratio_ of two such quantities (e.g., the ratio of some length and some other fixed unit of length).  Here, the ratio is replaced by difference, but otherwise it is conceptually the same.  I would argue that potential energy is physically meaningful, precisely as an element of an affine line and not as a number.  And, of course, since only numbers can be recorded, we must subtract elements of affine lines and divide elements of vector spaces.

Comment: @DeaneYang: As another example of a torsor (though no longer an affine space, but rather a torsor over the group U(1)) is the concept of _phase_ in quantum mechanics, e.g., the phase of an electron.  What can actually be measured as a number is the change of phase as the electron travels around a closed loop, which gives an element of U(1).  But the phase itself is an element of a U(1)-torsor, and this torsor depends on the position (so all torsors taken together form a principal U(1)-bundle).

Answer (score 15):

1. The action appears in an exponent, so it must be dimensionless. That then fixes the dimension of each term which appears in the action and "forbids you from proclaiming that $\phi$ is dimensionless".

<sub>To find the mass dimension of the field $\phi$ you can argue as follows: The action is the integral of the Lagrangian over $d$ space-time coordinates $x$, each of which has mass dimension $-1$, so the mass dimension of the Lagrangian is $d$. Hence the field $\phi$ must have mass dimension $d/2-1$ to ensure that the kinetic contribution $\propto (\partial\phi/\partial x)^2$ has mass dimension $d$.</sub>

2. Whether or not a coupling constant has a dimension will depend on the number of space-time dimensions in which you work, there is no fundamental difference between the various numbers.

<sub>A term $g_2 \phi^4$ will have a coupling constant $g_2$ of mass dimension $4-d$. In 3+1 space-time dimensions $g_2$ is dimensionless. Similarly, the coupling constant $g_1$ in the term $g_1\cdot \phi\partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi$ must have mass dimension $1-d/2$, which equals $-1$ for $d=4$.</sub>

Comment: FWIW this sounds like a physicist's answer. Not that I'm complaining, since my background is in physics and this is very much like the answer I would have given in that context, but I did find Dmitri's answer more useful for understanding the deeper mathematical foundation of units.

Comment: true, I'm a physicist, but what other other answer than this can one give to question #1 of the OP: _"What forbids me from proclaiming that $\phi$ is dimensionless instead of mass dimension 1"_ ?

Comment: Fair enough :-) Sorry, my comment came out sounding a little more dismissive than I meant it.